# Saving an ASP image with base64 src using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, image

I have this image:

```
<img id="mainPage_ChildContent1_img1" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD//gAEKgD/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEHN+sQHPrBZ5O4/2Q==">
```

src value reduced to preserve space in the example.

The original asp image control is declared this way:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img1"/>
```

The image is loaded through jQuery input type file in the image control.

I want to know how I can save the image to a file with C# once the user will click a save button.

ImageUrl property is null, what are my options to get the src in image object in C# code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your src in a input type hidden with Jquery.

**Example**

```
function storeImgsrc(){
 $("#hiddenid").val($("#imgid").src());
}
```

After that you can create a Bitmap or File in C#.